# Put 2 digit numbers in HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, hashmap, long-integer

I'm trying to write this code in java to parse input lines and save the number and the string into a HashMap:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        
        in = input.nextLine();
        tokens = in.split(delims);
        
        Long fi = Long.parseLong(tokens[0]);
        String si = tokens[1];
        
        songs.put(fi, si);
        
    }
```

now for a input like this it works:

> 1 one
>
> 2 two
>
> 3 three
>
> 4 four

but when i enter 2 digit numbers for example:

> 30 one
>
> 30 two
>
> 15 three
>
> 25 four

the result of println HashMap shows:

> four
>
> two
>
> three

I'm new with using HashMaps, is sth wrong with my code?
I used split method to parse input string and save it in a string array, and it seems to work right, so i think the problem should be sth about HashMap

Comment: Not clear what's the issue but in case you want your keys sorted, you need a `TreeMap<Long, String>` instead of a `HashMap<Long, String>`.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are adding the same key twice (the 30 Long value), so the first entry with the _"30"_ key gets overwritten .

Comment: better to use `LinkedHashMap` it can preserve you insertion Order.  But `HashMap` don't .

Answer (score 1):

When you do a `put` it replaced the previous value so if you try to put two values for the same key you get the last value you put.

You could use a MultiMap or `Map<Long, List<String>>` where the list of strings contains all the values for that key.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HashMapAnswer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Long, String> songs = new HashMap<Long, String>();
        String in;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            in = input.nextLine();
            String tokens[] = in.split(",");

            Long fi = Long.parseLong(tokens[0]);
            String si = tokens[1];

            songs.put(fi, si);
        }
        for (Map.Entry m : songs.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + m.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

[Sample screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oK76.png)